# Specify default value in systemd (PassEnvironment)

Tags: linux, systemd

So, in systemd we have a mechanism to pass environment variables to the process using [PassEnvironment](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).

Is it possible to specify default values for these variables in the systemd service file itself?

I have tried out `PassEnvironment='POLL_INTERVAL=10'` but it is not working.

Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Environment=` parameter instead. `PassEnvironment=` is used to pass variables whose values are defined within the systemd process itself (PID 1).

Example:

```
Environment=“VAR=string”
```

Comment: what if the variable is an environmental variable?